duplicate tailwindcss output in SSR production html
I'm using tailwindcss in my nuxt3 project via official @nuxtjs/tailwindcss
{
    "dependencies": {
        "nuxt": "^3.11.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.9.4"
    }
}


I import the package in nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: [
        '~/assets/scss/main.scss',
    ],
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    ],
});

since I have to define some custom style classes via tailwindcss, in my main.scss
@tailwind base;
@tailwind utilities;

.custom-class {
    @apply mx-2;
}

@layer base {
    *,
    ::before,
    ::after {
        @apply border-[var(--border-color)];
    }
}

Now everything works correctly, except the tailwindcss output has been rendered twice in production

the online production output
How to prevent the redundant tailwindcss render result?

Not sure you need to add any @tailwind in the main.scss file if you use the Nuxt module. Otherwise, if it doesn't come from that part, then inspect your project from other parts of your code that could import some other Tailwind somewhere. I'd say to mostly try to comment out parts of the code so that you could narrow down where it comes from, might be a CDN or something.

@kissu Thanks for your reply! I have to add @tailwind in main.scss or neither @apply nor @layer would compile correctly.
